# Distance of pixels Kinect

Tags: opencv, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am using OpenCV 2.6 and Kinect SDK 1.6 in my visual c++. How to get distance(Z-axis) from kinect sensor of any particular object/ pixel in 2D color image? I have tried NuiTransformSkeletonToDepthImage(..), that only provides skeleton distance. For my application I require distance between kinect and any pixel in the 2D color image. Please Help...

Answer (score -1):

To get the distance from a particular pixel, first of all you need to calculate 
`pixelIndex` from the current selected position. Add a new event handler for 
`depthImageControl_MouseDown`, which will handle the distance calculation.

Get the selected position by using the following code:

```
Point currentPoint = e.GetPosition(depthImageControl);
```

In the next step, calculate pixelIndex from the X and Y coordinates of the 
selected position:

```
int pixelIndex = (int)(currentPoint.X + ((int)currentPoint.Y * this.
frame.Width));
```

And finally, get the distance by using bit masking:

```
int distancemm = this.pixelData[pixelIndex] >> DepthImageFrame.
PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;
```

Comment: I am using visual c++...how can i do this in c++?